# Cross compiling node js on Windows CE using CMake

Tags: node.js, cmake, windows-ce, cmake-gui

I am in the process of cross compiling node js on Windows CE6-ARM and I am running into a lot of troubles.

I read somewhere that CMake can make the process slightly complicated.

I am not able to find any resource on how to compile node js for Windows CE using Cmake

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Windows CE is not a platform supported by node.js (or most of its dependencies), so I think you'll probably end up wasting a lot of time trying to get it to compile and work properly.

There is the Chakra Core port of node, but that's only the javascript engine and may not even be 100% compatible with Windows CE.